# Pure JS accordion menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Required menu structure implementation:

- Menu

  - submenu

    - contacts
    - news
    - photo
  - submenu
  - submenu
  - submenu
- menu
- menu
- menu

By clicking on the "menu" button, a list of "sub menu" elements opens. Clicking on the "sub menu" button opens a list of menu links. The task is next. By pressing the "menu" button it is necessary to close all other "menu" buttons. By clicking on the "sub menu" button, close all other "sub menu" buttons.

My code:

```
<https://codepen.io/artemkhmyrov/pen/oNMgGpd>
```

I only managed to go through the first level of the menu, that is, I click on the "menu" button and the list from the "sub menu" opens, I click on another "menu" button, the previous one closes, but when I click on the "sub menu" everything closes.

Comment: your code is not clear, try below example

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to add enough code to reproduce the problem **in the question itself**?  As explained in [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428), questions asking for help with off-site code are off topic for Stack Overflow.  If you need help trimming your code down for the question, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can help.

Answer (score 3):

For multilevel menu you can try like below,

```js
document.querySelector(".burger-menu__icon").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector('.burger-menu__box').style.top="2%";
  document.querySelector('.burger-menu__box').style.right = "51%";
  });

   
  const burgerMenu = document.querySelector(".burger-menu");
  const burgerMenuIcon = document.querySelector(".burger-menu__icon");
  const burgerMenuBox = document.querySelector(".burger-menu__box");
  const container = burgerMenuBox.querySelector(".container");
  const burgerMenuSub = container.querySelector(".burger-menu-sub");
  let burgerMenuTitle = burgerMenuSub.querySelectorAll(".burger-menu-title");
  let burgerMenuContent = burgerMenuSub.querySelectorAll(".burger-menu-content");

  

for (let i = 0; i < burgerMenuTitle.length; i++) {
  burgerMenuTitle[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    var menu1 = document.getElementsByClassName('menu1');
    for (var j = 0; j < menu1.length; j ++) {
      menu1[j].style.display="none";
    }
    burgerMenuContent[i].classList.toggle("burger-menu-content");
    burgerMenuContent[i].style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```css
    *,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 0.9944vw;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  width: 129.4rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header .container {
  display: flex;
}
.header__top {
  background-color: rgb(166, 170, 166);
  margin-bottom: 1.7rem;
}
.header__top .container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3.6rem;
}

.burger-icon {
  display: flex;
  width: 2.55rem;
  align-items: center;
  height: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
.burger-icon.active::after {
  transition: all 0.9s ease 0s;
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}
.burger-icon.active::before {
  transition: all 0.9s ease 0s;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.burger-icon::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.burger-icon::before,
.burger-icon::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: white;
  width: 0.2rem;
  height: 1.1rem;
}

.burger-menu {
  width: 3rem;
}
.burger-menu__icon {
  z-index: 15;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4862b6;
}
.burger-menu__icon span,
.burger-menu__icon:before,
.burger-menu__icon:after {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
.burger-menu__icon::before,
.burger-menu__icon::after {
  content: "";
}
.burger-menu__icon::before {
  top: 0;
}
.burger-menu__icon::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
.burger-menu__icon span {
  top: 50%;
  transform: scale(1) translate(0, -50%);
}
.burger-menu__icon._active span {
  transform: scale(0) translate(0, -50%);
}
.burger-menu__icon._active:before {
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -50%);
}
.burger-menu__icon._active:after {
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, 50%);
}
.burger-menu__box {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
  min-height: 31rem;
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  padding-top: 5rem;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  z-index: 11;
  border-radius: 0 0 1.5rem 1.5rem;
}
.burger-menu__box .container {
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 5rem;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.burger-menu__box._active {
  top: 0;
}
.burger-menu-content {
  margin-left: 2.4rem;
  display: none;
  right: 20%;
}
.burger-menu-content-open {
  display: block;
}
.burger-menu-title {
  padding: 1.1rem 0rem;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.burger-menu-title:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.burger-menu-title:hover > .burger-icon::before,
.burger-menu-title:hover > .burger-icon::after {
  color: #4862b6;
}
.burger-menu-title:hover a {
  color: #4862b6;
}
.burger-menu-sub {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.burger-menu__section-wrap-link {
  padding: 0rem 0rem 0.9rem 3rem;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
}
.burger-menu__section-link {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.burger-menu__section-link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 0.3rem solid transparent;
  border-left: 0.4rem solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 0.3rem solid transparent;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
}
.burger-menu__section-link:hover::before {
  border-left: 0.4rem solid #4862b6;
}
.burger-menu__section-links {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.burger-menu__sub-sub-link {
  padding: 0rem 0rem 0.9rem 0rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.burger-menu__sub-sub-title {
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0rem 0rem 0.9rem 0rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.burger-menu__sub-item {
  width: 25rem;
}
.burger-menu-list {
  width: 28.5rem;
}
.burger-menu__wrap-accordion {
  padding: 0rem 0rem 2.5rem 2.5rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 115rem;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.burger-menu__wrap-accordion::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.001rem;
  background: green;
}
.burger-menu__wrap-item {
  padding: 1rem 0rem;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>


<div class="burger-menu__icon">
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="burger-menu__box">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="burger-menu-sub menu">

      <div class="burger-menu__wrap-accordion">
        <ul class="burger-menu-list">
          <ul class="burger-menu-list">
            <li class="burger-menu__item">
            <li class="burger-menu-title">
              <div class="burger-icon"></div>
              <a href="#" class="burger-menu__sub-sub-link">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <ul class="burger-menu-content">
              <li class="burger-menu__sub-item">
                  <li class="burger-menu-title">
                    <div class="burger-icon"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="burger-menu__sub-sub-link">Sub Menu</a>
                  </li>
                  <ul class="burger-menu-content menu1">
                    <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 3</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="burger-menu__sub-item">
                  <li class="burger-menu-title">
                    <div class="burger-icon"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="burger-menu__sub-sub-link">Sub Menu</a>
                  </li>
                  <ul class="burger-menu-content menu1">
                    <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 3</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="burger-menu__sub-item">
                  <li class="burger-menu-title">
                    <div class="burger-icon"></div>
                    <a href="#" class="burger-menu__sub-sub-link">Sub Menu</a>
                  </li>
                  <ul class="burger-menu-content menu1">
                    <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                      <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 3</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="burger-menu-list">
            <li class="burger-menu__item">
            <li class="burger-menu-title">
              <div class="burger-icon"></div>
              <a href="#" class="burger-menu__sub-sub-link">Menu</a>
            </li>
            <ul class="burger-menu-content">
              <li class="burger-menu__sub-item">
              <li class="burger-menu-title">
                <div class="burger-icon"></div>
                <a href="#" class="burger-menu__sub-sub-link">Sub Menu</a>
              </li>
              <ul class="burger-menu-content menu1">
                <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                  <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                  <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                  <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="burger-menu__sub-item">
              <li class="burger-menu-title">
                <div class="burger-icon"></div>
                <a href="#" class="burger-menu__sub-sub-link">Sub Menu</a>
              </li>
              <ul class="burger-menu-content menu1">
                <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                  <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                  <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                  <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="burger-menu__sub-item">
              <li class="burger-menu-title">
                <div class="burger-icon"></div>
                <a href="#" class="burger-menu__sub-sub-link">Sub Menu</a>
              </li>
              <ul class="burger-menu-content menu1">
                <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                  <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                  <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="burger-menu__section-wrap-link">
                  <a href="#" class="burger-menu__section-link">Paragraph 3</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>

         
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
       

</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this structure is not suitable. Firstly, you need to implement that the menu opens on click, and secondly, when the menu is opened, the pseudo-element next to it should change from + to x. This code snippet already contains hundreds of menu links. Is it possible to use my code if there is a second nested menu, add an active class like I have with the first nested menu, and if there is an open menu somewhere, close it?

Comment: I also found this dropdown menu example but it didn't work. If not wrong

Comment: now check i made changes

Comment: The essence of the task is to limit the user's ability to open a hundred items. The user can open only one first level item and only one second level item (nested). In your example, I can open all "menus" and all "sub-menus". Is it possible to somehow limit the number of drop-down elements using JS?

Comment: @WiseNewbie now try again , i have made changes

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you rearrange your html view first.

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a>Menu</a>
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <a>Sub Menu</a>
                   <ul>
                      <li>Contacts</li>
                      <li>News</li>
                      <li>Photo</li>
                   </ul>
             </li>
             <li>Sub Menu</li>
             <li>Sub Menu</li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a>Menu</a>
    </li>
     /*-- and so on --*/
</ul>
```

From there, you can specify which `<li>` to expend through JavaScript.

Comment: I also suffered from this, I thought about how to do it right, thank you very much for the layout advice it will also come in handy for me but I need logic in JS